# How can a browser hijacking attack change the browser's default homepage?

Tags: web-browser, malware, browser-hijacking

Some attacks on web browsers consist simply of advertising, so the default homepage of the browser is changed (which is just a small aspect of browser-hijacking).
My question: is  installing (malicious) add-ons (via drive-by download attack) the only way to modifiy the browser's homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, installing addons is not the only way.  There have been a number of javascript methods over the years, many of which are no longer supported by most browsers.

However there is at least 1 method still possible that works on modern IE browsers: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ms531418(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/ms531418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

There are probably others.